# passing array objects to functions in cpp

Tags: c++, arrays

```
array <long double,3000> x,y;
```

This is the array object. I want to pass this into a function below

```
void calculate (array <long double,3000> ,array <long double,3000> );
```

and I used function call as shown below

```
calculate(x_value,y_value);
```

where `x_value` and `y_value` are the two array objects.

The function definition is

```
void fun_name(array <long double,3000> x_coordinate,array<long double,3000> y_coordinate)
```

My program runs correctly. But I want to know whether there is any short representation for passing the array objects to functions..

Comment: You can use a typedef to make it easier to read. Or a template to avoid having to specify the type altogether. And please pass things like arrays and vectors by reference.

Comment: Another option is `template<typename T, size_t N> void fun_name( array<T,N> x, array<T,N> y);` . No need to be afraid of templates :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you define a typename to shorten your type, as follows (an example)

```
using array3000 = array <long double,3000>;


void calculate (array3000 , array3000 ); // declaration


void fun_name(array3000 x_coordinate, array3000 y_coordinate)
{
    // definition
}


int main(){

    array3000 x,y;

    fun_name(x, y);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: void fun_name (& array3000 ,&  array3000 );  // declaration 
void fun_name(& array3000 x_coordinate, & array3000 y_coordinate)  { }
fun_name(x,y);
Does this help me to manipulate arrays using reference?

Comment: @richususan what do you mean? you want to pass by reference? If so than, void calculate (array3000 &,array3000 &);

Comment: I meant the same. But if I didn't use the reference, then also I can edit values of elements in arrays. What additional use can be obtained by passing array as a reference? i know one advantage ..that we can use sizeof and the rest??

Comment: For now you are passing by value. Which means copying 3000 long doubles into the function. This is time consuming tasks, especially if you have to do it lots, e.g. in a loop. With reference you dont have to worry about this. And if you are worrying about changing passed array values, then just pass by const reference.

Comment: this explains everything.. God bless u